# Creating a simple stored procedure that runs once per day in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am learning SQL and want to create a daily event that changes the `qualified` field to `true` when the `pending_expiry_date` field has been surpassed. I read that I could either use a stored procedure or a cronjob. Since I use postgres, I thought it might be easier to keep everything all in one place and use a stored procedure instead of a cronjob. However, I am getting an error with my code that tried to create it.

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_qualified_field() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    -- update qualified field to TRUE for any pending commissions where the pending_expiry_date has expired
    UPDATE commissions
    SET qualified = TRUE
    WHERE qualified = FALSE AND pending_expiry_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT update_qualified_field_schedule
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1 day' DO
$$
BEGIN
    PERFORM update_qualified_field();
END;
$$;
```

The syntax error (with part `update_qualified_field_schedule`):

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "update_qualified_field_schedule"
LINE 12: CREATE EVENT update_qualified_field_schedule
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 398
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS commissions(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_time TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
    referrer_user_id UUID REFERENCES users(id),
    customer_payment_id INTEGER REFERENCES customer_payments(id),
    qualified BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'FALSE' NOT NULL, -- i.e. qualified or pending
    pending_expiry_date TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '3 months') NOT NULL,
    last_modified TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

What am I doing wrong here? It says where the error is, but it doesn't say why it's a syntax error or how to fix it, which is unclear to me. I assume it might be something daft that I’m unaware of. Also, is my thought process and code ok, or does anyone have any further comments or tips or whether I should instead use something else, like `pg_agent`? Thank you

Comment: Where did you find the CREATE EVENT syntax? That’s not standard PostgreSQL, that’s not supported

Comment: As @FrankHeikens said there is no `CREATE EVENT` in Postgres per [SQL Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html). There is `CREATE EVENT TRIGGER` but that is something different. You are probably looking for  [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) or [pg_timetable](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_timetable) which are extensions you would need to install.

Comment: You misread, or it was mis-written, the suggestion should be *stored procedure **and** a cron job.* If your you want to keep the idea of keeping it all in one place then look into implementing the pg_cron extension.

Comment: Ok, thank you all. I will investigate using pg_cron. I was asking Chat GPT and it suggested the `CREATE EVENT` method!